# How could localized sites translate strings before the update actually rolled out?

Tags: discussion, support, localization, russian-stackoverflow, transifex

We have questions about that on ru Stack Overflow:

- [Как в локализованных сообществах заранее узнавать о нововведениях в сети SE?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7705/15479)
- [Нет перевода текстов на индикаторах новичков](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7704/15479).
- [Нет перевода строк в фильтрах](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9046/15479).

The questions were created after Contributor Indicator feature has been released without being localized.

In Transifex those strings have appeared the same day this feature was released.

It would have been great if you added those strings into Transifex at least a few days before the new feature rolled out.

Comment: Question to the general audience related to this question: do roll-outs have a beta period?  Could an open Beta be the answer?